# [Spring][Actuators] Failed to process import candidates for configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to implement actuators in my spring project (NOT spring boot). I added below dependency in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also added the class below:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import({EndpointAutoConfiguration.class, PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootActuatorConfigBindings {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(Collection<? extends MvcEndpoint> endpoints) {
        return new EndpointHandlerMapping(endpoints);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EndpointMvcAdapter metricsEndPoint(MetricsEndpoint delegate) {
        return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
    }
}
```

But on running i am getting below error:

> [local] [] [ERROR] [2019-04-22T14:24:47,347] [     Console scanner]
>   [work.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [com.mycompany.ans.processor.bindings.ProcessorBindings]; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect
>   annotated methods on class
>   com.mycompany.ans.processor.bindings.SpringBootActuatorConfigBindings
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:302)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>   [spring-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>   [spring-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:952)
>   [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
>   [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:917)
>   [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
>   [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
>   [jetty-webapp-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
>   [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
>   [jetty-webapp-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847)
>   [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
>   [jetty-servlet-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
>   [jetty-webapp-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
>   [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.restartWebApp(JettyRunMojo.java:517)
>   [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.ConsoleScanner.restartWebApp(ConsoleScanner.java:112)
>   [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.ConsoleScanner.checkSystemInput(ConsoleScanner.java:76)
>   [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.ConsoleScanner.run(ConsoleScanner.java:46)
>   [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated
>   methods on class
>   com.mycompany.ans.processor.bindings.SpringBootActuatorConfigBindings
>           at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:392)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:317)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:589)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:649)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:555)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>           at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:158)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:392)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:317)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:589)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]

Where i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your Exception logs:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.mycompany.ans.processor.bindings.SpringBootActuatorConfigBindings
  at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:392) ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:317) ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:589) ~[spring-context-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
  ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
  org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
...
```

You need to include the dependency for Spring Web mvc, from which the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` class is implemented and required. This is the cause of the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```